# Thunderbolt 3 Expansion Card QXP-T32P not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I purchased and installed the following Thunderbolt expansion: https://www.qnap.com/en/product/thunderbolt3-expansion-card

And can not for the life of me get this to work with Ubuntu.
I tried erasing Ubuntu and installing Windows to check if it worked, and it worked perfectly with Windows.
Back to Ubuntu, and it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked here for help? https://www.qnap.com/en/compatibility/

Comment: The card is not listed.

Comment: Send them a email or something for support.